# How I can fetch email data from User table in my OrderServiceImpl.java class

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

How to get emailId From User table in the OrderServiceImpl.java class so that it can be sent
as a String while calling sendTextEmail(String email) in
OrderServiceImpl.java class?

**User.java Class**

```
@Setter
@Getter
@EqualsAndHashCode
@ToString
@NoArgsConstructor
//@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "`user`", uniqueConstraints = {@UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "email")})
public class User {

  public User(String email, String name, String password, String address) {
      this.email = email;
      this.name = name;
      this.password = password;
      this.address = address;
  }

  @Id
  @Column(name = "userId")
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  private Long id;
  
  @Size(max = 50)
  @Email
  private String email;
  @Size(max = 50)
  @NotBlank
  private String name;
  @Size(max = 100)
  @NotBlank
  private String password;
  @Size(max = 50)
  @NotBlank
  private String address;
  
  @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @JoinTable(name = "cart", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "userId"),
  inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name  = "foodId"))
  private List<Food> cart = new ArrayList<Food>();
  
  @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @JoinTable(name = "user_roles", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "userId"),
  inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name  = "roleId"))
  private Set<Role> roles = new HashSet<Role>();

}
```

**Order.java Class**

```
@Setter
@Getter
@EqualsAndHashCode
@ToString
@NoArgsConstructor
//@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "orders", uniqueConstraints = {@UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "orderTransaction")})
public class Order {
    
    @Id
    @Column(name = "orderId")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    
    @Size(max = 50)
    @NotBlank
    private String orderTime;
    
    @Size(max = 50)
    @NotBlank
    private String orderTransaction;
    
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name = "users_orders", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "orderId"),
    inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name  = "userId"))
    private List<Order> orders = new ArrayList<Order>();

}
```

**EmailServiceImpl.java Class**

```
@Service
public class EmailServiceImpl implements EmailService {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory
            .getLogger(EmailServiceImpl.class);
    @Autowired
    private JavaMailSender javaMailSender;

    @Override
    //Sending User Object
    public void sendTextEmail(String email) {
        logger.info("Simple Email sending start");

        SimpleMailMessage simpleMessage = new SimpleMailMessage();
        simpleMessage.setTo(email); //Enter customer email 
        simpleMessage.setSubject("Spring Boot=> Sending simple email");
        simpleMessage.setText("Dear hunger buddy customer Hope you are doing well.");
        javaMailSender.send(simpleMessage);

        logger.info("Simple Email sent");

    }
}
```

OrderServiceImpl.java Class

```
@Service
public class OrderServiceImpl implements OrderService{

    private static final String String = null;
    @Autowired
    private EmailService emailService;
    @Autowired
    private OrderRepo orderRepo;
    
    /*@Autowired 
    private User register;*/
    
    @Override
    public Order addOrder(Order order) throws AlreadyExistsException {
        if(orderRepo.existsById(order.getId())) {
            throw new AlreadyExistsException("This record already exists");
        }
        else
        {
        
            //long temp=order.getId();
            //Optional<User> optional = userRepo.findById(temp);
            String email = null;
            emailService.sendTextEmail(email);
            
            return orderRepo.save(order);
            
        }
    }
    
    @Override
    public Optional<List<Order>> getAllOrder() {
        return Optional.ofNullable(orderRepo.findAll());
    }

    @Override
    public Optional<Order> getOrderById(Long id) throws IdNotFoundException {
        Optional<Order> optional = orderRepo.findById(id);
        if (!optional.isPresent()) {
            throw new IdNotFoundException("Sorry Order Not Found");
        }
        return optional;
    }
}
```

I have removed all the import statement to save the time of reader.

ThankYou

Comment: Shouldn't an order have a reference to a user? You are currently having no link between User and Order

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have a logical issue in `Order` entity definition. `Order` does not contain another list of Orders. But it should contain the `User` who placed the order. Hence, the definition should be corrected as follows:

```java
@Setter
@Getter
@EqualsAndHashCode
@ToString
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "orders", uniqueConstraints = {@UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "orderTransaction")})
public class Order {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "orderId")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    
    @Size(max = 50)
    @NotBlank
    private String orderTime;
    
    @Size(max = 50)
    @NotBlank
    private String orderTransaction;
    
    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name = "users_orders", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "orderId"),
    inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name  = "userId"))
    private User user;
}
```

Then in `OrderServiceImpl` you could access user information with following:

```java
User user = order.getUser();
String emailId = user.getEmail();
```